# C# Find Number of elements present in array

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want to create static class which is generic. That class should pass through each property and check if is array. If result is true, than class should check how many elements are present in class and to return that number.

What I had did till now:

```
public static class Helper<T> where T : class
{
    private static int _counter = 0;
    public static int Counter()
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.PropertyType.IsArray)
            {

            }
        }

        return _counter;
    }
}
```

I need help how to get number of present elements in array.

Comment: Is `T` supposed to be a static class type or an instance type?

Comment: @ikkentim it is supposed to be a class

Comment: Then on what instance should it check how many elements are in the array? EDIT: Or do you merely want to count the number of properties which are of an array type?

Comment: @ikkentim since it's no object is passed to the Counter method, I guess it's static.

Comment: What in case if is instance type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also want to use it on a instanced object instead of an Type you could do s.th. like this (remove the generic type of `Helper` and make the `Counter` method generic):

```cs
public static class Helper
{
    // This method will only iterate the public static properties
    public static int Counter<T>() where T : class => Counter(typeof(T), null);

    // This method will iterate all public properties
    public static int Counter<T>(T objectToCount) where T : class
    {
        if(objectToCount == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(objectToCount));
        }

        return Counter(typeof(T), objectToCount);
    }

    public static int Counter(Type type, object instance)
    {
        int _counter = 0;

        PropertyInfo[] properties = null;
        if(instance == null)
        {
            properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        }
        else
        {
            properties = type.GetProperties();
        }

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.PropertyType.IsArray)
            {
                var array = property.GetValue(instance, null) as Array;
                var length  = array?.Length;

                // do s.th. with your counter
            }
        }

        return _counter;
    }
}
```

then you could use it like:

```
Helper.Counter(x);
Helper.Counter<TestClass>();
Helper.Counter<TestClass>(x);
```

---

**Update:**

for only instanced objects it could be simplified to this:

```cs
public static int Counter(object objectToCount) 
{
    if(objectToCount == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(objectToCount));
    }

    int _counter = 0;
    foreach (var property in objectToCount.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.PropertyType.IsArray)
        {
            var array = property.GetValue(objectToCount, null) as Array;
            var length = array?.Length;

            // do s.th. with your counter
        }
    }

    return _counter;
}
```

Comment: I'm using this in Controller which is taking parameters [FromBody], when I pass data and when get on line var array = property.GetValue(null, null) as Array; it is getting exception non staic method requires a target

Comment: @DanijelBoksan do you need it only instanced or also generic?

Comment: at the moment need only instanced.

Comment: @DanijelBoksan if the Generic method is too much I added also a more simple solution only allowing instances

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question right, you want to get the number of array properties of a class.
in this case, you could choose two approaches.
extention method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int NumbeofArays<TClass>(this TClass entry) where TClass : class, new()
    {
        Type type = typeof(TClass);
        int arrays = 0;
        foreach (var propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
        {
            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsArray)
                arrays = arrays + 1;
        }

        return arrays;
    }
}
```

Or a Helper Class:

```
public static class ClassHelper<TClass> where TClass : class, new()
{
    static ClassHelper()
    {
        Type type = typeof(TClass);
        int arrays = 0;
        foreach (var propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
        {
            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsArray)
                arrays = arrays + 1;
        }

        NumberofArrays = arrays;
    }

    public static int NumberofArrays { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int Counter()
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
        if (property.PropertyType.IsArray)
        {
            var array = property.GetValue(null, null) as Array;
            Console.WriteLine(array.Length);
        }
    }

    return _counter;
}
```

example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2ICron

Comment: it'll fail if the class also has some instanced properties, you at least need `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static` as argument for `GetProperties` [see dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BN0sjo)